# Difference in declaring a function in Python and C

Tags: python, c

I am reading and learning now Python and C at the same time. (Don't ask me why, it is a lot of fun! :-))
I use "Learning Python" by Mark Lutz. Here is what he writes about functions in Python:

> Unlike in compiled languages such as C, Python functions do not need
>   to be fully defined before the program runs. More generally, defs are
>   not evaluated until they are reached and run, and the code inside defs
>   is not evaluated until the functions are later called.

I do not quite get it as in my second book K.N.King says that you CAN declare a function first and create a definition later.

English is not my native language so what I am missing here?

I can make only one guess, that it is somehow related to program runtime. In C the compiler runs through the program and finds the function declaration. Even if it is not defined, compiler goes on and finds function definition later. Function declaration in C helps to avoid problems with return-type of a function (as it is int by default). On the other hand in Python function is not evaluated until it is reached during runtime. And when it is reached, it does not evaluate the body of a function until there is a function call. But this guess does not explain a quote above.

What is then Mr.Lutz is talking about? I am confused a bit...

Comment: python is also compiled...

Comment: "defs are not evaluated until they are reached and run" means to me (also learning Python :-), you can even have an error in a function body, but until execution doesn't reach a call to that function, the error is unnoticed

Comment: @rolika, depends on the error. Syntax errors will cause a crash before the program begins to execute. Other errors will wait until you reach the problem line.

Comment: "return-type of a function (as it is int by default)"  You need to get a new C book which is not several decades old. Implicit int has been removed from the C language long time ago.

Comment: @Kevin, you're right, i just tried in IDLE.

Comment: @Lundin when was it removed? This is a 2008 book, C89 and C99.

Comment: @NikolayDudaev It was removed 1999, 16 years ago. If your book tells you otherwise, it is a bad book.

Comment: @Lundin: That said, many compilers still use an ancient language standard by default (or compile with non-strict checks) that would allow old K&R constructs to work. It's good to know that _can_ happen so you know how to fix it, even if it's dumb and shouldn't.

Comment: @ShadowRanger When developing new programs, nobody should accept crap compilers. It is very important that beginners in particular learn the current C standard and not some ancient version of it. For example, I don't understand why people accept that gcc comes as "compile your program as some sort of GNU crap" by default, instead of being set to "compile your program according to standard C" by default.

Comment: @Lundin: Hey, you're preaching to the choir on writing modern code. Sadly, you don't get to be a purist when working with legacy code, so you need to know the quirks. If your million line application was written with non-strict compilation assumed, it will probably fail to compile, and have 10,000 warnings (admittedly, a few thousand of them probably point out real problems, and the rest probably make it non-portable) if you switch on `-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werrors`, and insisting on stopping work until the code base is clean isn't likely to work.

Comment: I have to agree here with @ShadowRanger. C is so old and there is a lot of code from the past that you better be aware of those kind of things. Of course the book is not 100% correct but I would say it is not 100% wrong. But thanks Lundin for pointinng this out.

Answer (score 5):

Python functions are 'executed' when the source code comes to them:

```
def foo():
    return bar

def bar():
    return 'spam'
```

Here `foo` depends on `bar`, but it doesn't matter that the `bar` function definition is not executed until after `foo` has been declared. Only when you then *call* `foo()` does the name `bar` need to exist.

In C however, you cannot do the above without an additional prototype declaration:

```c
char * bar(void);

char * foo(void) {
    return bar();
}

char * bar(void) {
    return "spam";
}
```

So yes, you *can* postpone the full declaration of `bar` but the compiler demands that you still declare the function signature up front.

So Python doesn't care whether or not `bar` is defined until runtime, C requires functions to be declared at compile time.

Comment: No, C allows for implicit prototypes (although I wouldn't recommend that you use that feature).

Comment: @skyking: right, where unknown functions are considered returning `int`, right? Unless you use C99 or C11 I think that'll still give you a compiler warning at least.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes. Correct.

Comment: Thanks, you made it simple but clear. I think, I got the point.

Answer (score 4):

In python you have no such thing as forward declarations. Symbols referenced in a function (code) does not get looked up until the function is called. That's why you don't need to define the function in order. For example

```
def foo():
    return bar()

def bar():
    return 42

foo()
```

First of all this is all compiled, but I'll skip those details. The code when executed will first define a function named `foo` with the body/code that says "find something called `bar` and call it and then return the return value". The similar happens for `bar`. And last at `foo()` the interpreter runs the code saying "find something named `foo` and call it". It this point `foo` is defined so it's called and it's body is executed, but that says "find something called `bar` and call it", but at this point we already has passed the point where `bar` is defined.

Now let's look at C:

```
int foo() {
    return bar();
}

int bar() {
    return 42;
}
```

now we have some slight problem here because the name lookup have to be done at build time, that's not a big problem here, but keep in mind that the C compiler processes the source sequentially so it will not look ahead. So when compiling `foo` it sees that you're trying to call something called `bar` which the compiler has no idea what it is - so it **assumes** that you've used `bar` correctly and figures out that it's a function taking no arguments and returns an `int` (no arguments passed, and by default it assumes it returns int). Then when you reach the definition of `bar` lucky you that the assumtion was correct (because the compiler has already made up his mind and generated code in `foo` assuming that - otherwise you would get odd behaviour). Last (when linking) it will resolve all symbols (no matter which order you put the declarations) and the placeholder for the name will just be a reference to what the name refers to. At this point the implementation could drop the names as they have no purpose for the program any more (but may select to keep them as it may help if you need to debug the program).

Now if you would like to be a little more secure you would have forward declarated `bar` so that the compiler can check that you actually calls it with arguments of correct type (and interpret the return value as the correct type). You would then have:

```
int bar(void);

int foo(void) {
    return bar();
}

int bar(void) {
    return 42;
}
```

If you did program in C++ this later way of doing it would be mandatory since C++ doesn't allow for guessing the parameter types, but also you're recommended to do so in C too (there's compiler warnings that warns for in the first C example that the compiler have to guess what `bar` is).

Answer (score 1):

Sample python:

```
foo()
def foo():
    #some code
```

That errors as the python interpreter didn't find any function before it is called. But:

```
def foo():
    bar() #just declared and not called yet

def bar():
    print("42")
foo() #now it is called and bar() is also got interpreted
```

This will print `42` without any error, as the interpreter has interpreted and executed the previous lines until foo() was called in the end.

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, `text_func` isn't defined when we first start the execution. In python, function are defined at runtime, when we execute the def line.

```
print ('Entry point. No custom functions/methods are defined at this point')

print ('Defining test_func')
# We defined a function here.
# The function is defined at runtime since python when we run this line
def test_func():
    # Obviously, the body of the function is executed only when we call the function.
    # Not when we define it
    print ('evaluating test_func now')


print ('test_func is now defined.')

test_func()
```

Answer (score 0):

In C you can compile without declaring, the compiler assumes the function
is int, if that's the case your program compiles and runs.
If your function or functions are another type you'll get problems and you'll have to declare. It is often quicker to not declare and generate your declarations from your code to an h file and include where needed. You can leave it to a program to write this part of your program. Just like you can leave the indent, write a big mess and let indent do it for you.